# Creating app an API to access and store Client Data. Is Oauth 2 a good choice for user authorization?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I want to create a mobile app that can access a RESTful API that I will write. To access that API, I wanted to use Oauth2 to Authorize the mobile app.

Is this a valid use of Oauth? Or should I only be using an Authentication service?

Edit:
What I'm trying to make sure I understand is the context that Oauth should be used it. My idea was to validate a username & password then return an authorization token, then use that token as an API key for the mobile application.

Comment: You're mixing different levels here. Oauth2 is a protocol. Many authentication services support Oauth2 as their API.

Comment: @cowbert I edited my question to explain what I am trying to do. I am new to Oauth and trying to understand what it is used for. (In an effort to make my own applications more secure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can defiently use oAuth for this.